# Split string into array in shell script based on regex delimiter

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, escaping

I have a string variable called `JAVA_OPTS` with various parameters in shell script.

```
-Dmaven.repo.local=/home/wangc/.m2/repository -Dtestparameter="some   spaces" --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
```

I'd like to split it into an array based on spaces, but not the space defined in escaped double quotes. For example I'd like to see an array with 3 elements:

```
-Dmaven.repo.local=/home/wangc/.m2/repository
-Dtestparameter="some   spaces" 
--add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
```

I have tried

```
IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$JAVA_OPTS"
```

But it can't tell the different space between double quotes, and return a four elements array as:

```
-Dmaven.repo.local=/home/wangc/.m2/repository
-Dtestparameter="some
spaces" 
--add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: Why do you want to read the string into an array? What are you trying to archive?

Comment: With some mild adaptation, the proposed duplicate will solve your problem

Comment: Related: [SU: How to split a string with quotes (like command arguments) in bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/1066455/)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you require a regex solution? Getting the shell itself to parse this is significantly easier.

```sh
array=(-Dmaven.repo.local=/home/wangc/.m2/repository -Dtestparameter="some   spaces" --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED)
```

Detouring the values via a string variable `$JAVA_OPTS` is precisely the wrong thing to do here, and makes the problem signicicantly harder.

Comment: I want to keep double quotes as -Dtestparameter="some   spaces", your example would swallow the double quotes and store it as -Dtestparameter=some spaces. please try `array=(-Dmaven.repo.local=/home/wangc/.m2/repository -Dtestparameter=\"some   spaces\" --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED)`

Comment: I'm guessing you are confused about what the quotes mean. Once the shell has parsed them, the actual string doesn't have any quotes.